# sql-server devide into groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following data

```
CREATE TABLE customers (ID INT, rankVal INT);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.customers( ID, rankVal )
VALUES  ( 1, -- ID - int
          1  -- rankVal - int
          ),
          ( 1, -- ID - int
          2 -- rankVal - int
          ),
          ( 2, -- ID - int
          1  -- rankVal - int
          ),
          ( 2, -- ID - int
          2  -- rankVal - int
          ),


          ( 3, -- ID - int
          1  -- rankVal - int
          ),
          ( 3, -- ID - int
          3 -- rankVal - int
          ),
          ( 4, -- ID - int
          1  -- rankVal - int
          ),
          ( 4, -- ID - int
          3  -- rankVal - int
          );
```

I want to devide my customers into groups. For example costumer 1 and 2 have the exactly same rankvals, they must be in a single group, customer 3 and 4 must be in different group. Expected results are

```
Grp  costumerID
---- -----------
gr1  1
gr1  2
gr2  3
gr2  4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `STRING_AGG` (SQL Server 2017 and above) to get all ranks in one and then `DENSE_RANK` to calculate group's number:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ID, STRING_AGG(rankVal,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rankVal) AS s
  FROM customers
  GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT CONCAT('grp', DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY s)) AS GRP, ID AS customerID
FROM cte;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6dd4a7d1f9efba995123bee25cbd93e7)**

Comment: Shouldn't `String_Agg( rankVal, ',' )` have an `order by` clause to ensure that the lists of ranks are predictably ordered and therefore comparable?

Comment: @HABO Yes, to get stable result `ORDER BY` is necessary :) Thanks